# Compound adjective "free-molecule" vs. "free molecular"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I've been asked by a reviewer to change all occurrences of "free-molecule", which I use consistently throughout my manuscript, to "free-molecular".  Typical usage examples: "particles colliding in the free-molecule regime", "calculations based on the free-molecule theory".

My question is, which of the possible four combinations below is grammatically correct/incorrect and why, and which would you recommend to use (my personal preference is 1)?  Are there any rules to guide the choice?

1. free-molecule
2. free molecule
3. free molecular
4. free-molecular

Comment: Please edit the question and add a few distinct sentences showing how you are using the phrase.  Do you ever have any word other than regime after free-molecule?

Comment: @jwpat7: Checking in NGrams it seems by far the most common context for this expression is in fact the [Free-molecular regime](http://www.personal.psu.edu/rsm209/Proposal/node57.html). Even if the word following is "theory", or "flow", for example, they're all basically about the same thing, so I don't think that matters. All that counts is the expression is *adjectival*.

Comment: These four things may have different (connotation/meaning/frequency of use) in a particular technical area than they do in the general language.  So I would assume the reviewer knows what is going on.

Comment: @GEdgar: Let's face it, *free molecules* of any kind, doesn't mean much to most users of "general language". And like I said, all the specialist stuff is about the same thing - [The Free-molecular aka Knudsen Regime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knudsen_number)

Answer (score 2):

There's no strong case for any one form being better than the others. I can't graph the hyphenated forms separately in [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free%20molecule,free%20molecular&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) - but they are included, and looking through a few pages it seems they're about equally common when the term is used adjectivally (the hyphen is rarely/never present when used as a noun, but surprisingly the noun usage isn't particularly common).

[image]

So the short answer is this is a matter of stylistic preference. Whether OP should comply with his reviewer's request therefore depends on how strongly he prefers his original, and how important it is not to upset the reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged says

- **gram molecule** is a *noun*
- **gram-molecular** is an *adjective*

Constructing by analogy:

- **free molecule** is a *noun*
- **free-molecular** is an *adjective*

Bottom line: *free molecule* is a noun, not an adjective. So the correct form is *free-molecular*, as in *free-molecular regime* (a regime of free molecules) or *free-molecular theory* (a theory pertaining to free molecules).

Comment: If there's a discrepancy between what MW says and what they write in the specialist literature, I think you have to go on usage, not prescriptive grammar. There are probably more instances of *free-molecule flow* with a hyphen than without. The writers clearly intend *free-molecule* as an adjectival modifier to *flow*, not a noun. And as for *gram molecular*, I think they're plain wrong - over recent decades the hyphenless version seems to have become the most common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's a distinct difference between gram **molecule** and **gram-molecular**. And free **molecular**, which is indeed an adjective (hyphenated or not), is [what I see](http://www.personal.psu.edu/rsm209/Proposal/node57.html) favored over free **molecule** (hyphenated or not) more often than not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also, you said yourself in your comment under the OP's question that _free molecular regime_ was the most common occurrence in the literature. Are you arguing against yourself now?

Comment: I'm primarily saying that in situations like this, usage rather than dictionaries determines what's "correct". And in MW's specific case of *gram-molecular*, the dictionary does **not** reflect the current dominant form (where the hyphen is *usually* omitted in more recent stuff). With *molecule/molecular*, both versions are about equally common, and hyphenation is about evenly split as well, so I don't think you can really give an answer saying one combination is "right" based on analogy with something in MW that seems to be actually "wrong".

Comment: @FumbleFingers My basic point is, _free molecule_ is a noun, and the OP is trying to modify _regime_, etc. with it when an adjective (_free molecular_) is the part of speech to use. Any editor I've worked with would flag the OP's usage simply for that.